# 'List' does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a method where I can pass a `Linq` expression as a parameter to return a new list of items.

Currently I am doing this ([based off this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299534/linq-passing-lambda-expression-as-parameter-to-be-executed-and-returned-by-meth)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Collection<T> {

    List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public Collection<T> Filter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query) {
        Collection<T> c = new Collection<T>();
        c = items.Where(query);
        return c;
    }
}
```

> 'List' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Where(IQueryable, Expression>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

I am not exactly sure what to do here to fix this.

Comment: For [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) you need to pass it a `Func<TSource, bool>` which is not what your `query` is.

Comment: When you do `c = items.Where(query);`, you are not filling the collection but (trying to) create a new one. See Rene Vogt's answer for a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`List<T>` is not `IQueryable<T>` but `IEnumerable<T>`. For the `Where` extension for `IEnumerable<T>` you can only pass a delegate not an expression.

I guess you want something like that:

```
public Collection<T> Filter(Func<T, bool> query) // only the lambda, NO expression
{
    Collection<T> c = new Collection<T>(items.Where(query).ToList());
    return c;
}
```

Note that `Where` only returns an `IEnumerable<T>` but not an `Collection<T>`. So you need to convert `c` to a `List<T>` and pass this to the constructor of `Collection<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must use an expression, there are a couple of things you could do. You can do something like this:

```
public ICollection<T> Filter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query) {     
    return items.AsQueryable().Where(query).ToList();
}
```

Converting you `IList` to a `Queryable` or you could do this:

```
public ICollection<T> Filter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query) {     
    return items.Where(query.Compile()).ToList();
}
```

Compiling your expression to a `Func<T, bool>`